# How to give background color to SliverGrid?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, sliver-grid

For `ListView` or `GridView` we wrap it with `Container`. But how can I give background color to `SliverGrid`?

Comment: hi, do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I'll just drop my solution here. I wrap my individual items with Container and give padding.

When the last row is not complete, I just add dummy item which is a Container with bg color until row is filled.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`DecoratedSliver`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DecoratedSliver-class.html) as wrapper around `SliverGrid`.

This way, you can give any part of your `Sliver*` a decoration.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could wrap your CustomScrollView by a Container having a background color:

```
Container(
    color: Colors.grey[200],
    child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[]
    )
)
```

Comment: See this issue : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62818
Your answer gives a background to the whole CustomScrollView, not to SliverGrid.

Comment: this is for whole CustomScrollView, not for SliverGrid